# Getting parameters of the Parrot ANAFI Drone

Tags: sensor, parameters, parrot

I have a Parrot ANAFI Drone. And I want to get its parameters such as height, yaw, pitch, roll angles , velocity, status etc.
But I do not know how to reach these parameters.
I use olypme SDK on python but it is not enough to get the parameters.
If someone helps regarding getting the parameters, I will be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an SDK-specific question, so your best bet will be to [consult the documentation](https://developer.parrot.com/docs/olympe/olympeapi.html).

From that, it seems all you need to do is instantiate the `olympe.Drone` class and make use of the [getMessage function call](https://developer.parrot.com/docs/olympe/olympeapi.html#olympe.Drone), which takes an [arsdk message](https://developer.parrot.com/docs/olympe/userguide/basics/explore_commands.html) which can include querying for a [gimbal state](https://developer.parrot.com/docs/olympe/arsdkng_gimbal.html).